# Dispatch different actions in redux

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I have a (React) container component. It's children need different data from different api endpoints, so I want to dispatch 2 actions the same time (both are asynchronous).

This doesn't seem to be possible. If I have both dispatches, the `activeSensors` are always empty...

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    userData: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    activeSensors: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  static contextTypes = {
    store: React.PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { store } = this.context;
    store.dispatch(fetchActiveSensorDataForAllSensors());
    store.dispatch(fetchUserData());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AnalyticsPanel activeSensors={this.props.activeSensors}/>
        <SearchCustomer userData={this.props.userData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect((state)=> {
  return {
    userData: state.userData.data,
    activeSensors: state.activeSensorsAll.sensors
  }
})(Dashboard);
```

EDIT: See the source for the full component.

Comment: You need to provide more code in your example. What you've posted should work--what does your `connect` look like? What are your reducers doing? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the `this.context.store.dispatch` method your code uses, but I don't think that its necessarily the way you should be doing things. Primarily because it really muddies the line between [container and presentational component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.y3b72fq8g)s. Presentational components don't need access to `store`, and there are other methods to do this which don't have this (albeit pedantic) drawback.

My component files typically look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';

export class Container from React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    // Most conical way

    const { fetchActiveSensorDataForAllSensors, fetchUserData } = this.props;
    fetchActiveSensorDataForAllSensors();
    fetchUserData();

    // Less conical way
    // const { dispatch } = this.props;
    // const { fetchActiveSensorDataForAllSensors, fetchUserData } = actions;
    // dispatch(fetchActiveSensorDataForAllSensors());
    // dispatch(fetchUserData());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AnalyticsPanel activeSensors={this.props.activeSensors}/>
        <SearchCustomer userData={this.props.userData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    activeSensors: state.activeSensorsAll.sensors,
    userData: state.userData.data
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Container);
```

Comment: see my edit, I've added the full component. Only diff actuall is that I don't parse the dispatch actions to the components within connect (which I don't need to do)

Comment: I updated my answer for fix where I copied your code and didn't update it; see changes to `componentWillMount`. This should work--if it doesn't, you'll need to confirm that your actions are actually firing like you think they are, and then determine if they reducer is updating the state object properly. I've also edited my `actions` import/connect so there isn't a scope conflict.

Comment: ok, this works, but please explain why this works. Why to I need to parse the actions to the connection function?

Comment: You don't need to (see my 'less conical way'), really. The problem is with how you're getting ahold of `store.dispatch`. When you use `connect`, regardless of whether you pass in actions, you will get `dispatch` as a prop. This is how you're supposed to access `dispatch`. I've never seen someone try to get it out of `this.context`, so even if `this.context.store` is a real thing, you just shouldn't do it that way.

Comment: This is a way that has been described by Dan himself. See here. https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-passing-the-store-down-implicitly-via-context?series=getting-started-with-redux

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for sharing. I've never seen this in the examples or on GH issues. Good to know. Though, I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work at the moment.